# How to concat string in PHP

Tags: php, loops

I want to do like this:

```
$string = "";
$string += "lol"; //maybe =+  > tried but both not working
```

But it isn't working, anyone suggestions?
Google isn't making my life easy (cant search characters like  = or +)

Comment: This code will eventually time out on you

Comment: Here's an overview: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: `while (1=1){` is the cause of the problem, isn't it? You can't assign a value to `1`, IIRC

Comment: How did this question garner 25 upvotes? SMH...

Comment: @miken32 No idea; but I hammered it just now.

Answer (score 75):

In PHP, string concatenation is done with the `.` operator:

```
$string .= 'lol';
```

`+` is for addition.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "";
while(...){
$str .= "lol.";
}
```

Replace the ellipses with your loop condition, (+=) is an addition assignment operator that adds the value of the right operand to a variable and assigns the result to the variable.